# My Solr Core1 (mutlicore) is not working?

Tags: solr, multicore, solrj

I am trying for multicores somehow i am able to run my core0 but core1 is not finding. 404 err0r is there can any buddy tell me what is the right configuration in solr.xml.

I am preferring sorl wiki core admin help.

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide your actual configuration in solrconfig.xml and also how you set up your installation?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<solr persistent="true" sharedLib="lib">
 <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
  <core name="core0" instanceDir="core0" />
  <core name="core1" instanceDir="core1" />
 </cores>
</solr>

Comment: core 0 is working fine at : http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/select?q=*:*

Comment: core1 have 404 error at : http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/select?q=*:*

Comment: I am new to solr. I am using following: java -Dsolr.solr.home=multicore -jar start.jar

Comment: the "instanceDir" attribute must correspond to a real folder name on your path (ie: core0 and core1 must be folders). also did you check your admin configs (?q=admin/settings/apachesolr/settings, or directly from solr admin panel) for your cores to point at the correct directories each?

Answer (score 1):

As it is described [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin), solr.xml should look like :

```
<solr persistent="true" sharedLib="lib">
    <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
        <core name="core0" instanceDir="core0" />
        <core name="core1" instanceDir="core1" />
    </cores>
</solr>
```

And your solr directory should be like :

```
-solr
    -core0
        +conf
        +data
    -core1
        +conf
        +data
    +lib
    solr.xml
```

Also run create core for adding new cores. The command for creating core is :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=coreX&instanceDir=path_to_instance_directory&config=config_file_name.xml&schema=schem_file_name.xml&dataDir=data
```

You should give more details about your problem, in order to get detailed answer.

Comment: Multicore
    -core0
        +conf
        +data
    -core1
        +conf
        +data
    +lib
    solr.xml